# How to get Gesture events by using silverlight framework?

Tags: windows-phone-7, gestures

I try to search available option about wp7 gesture. I found only Silverlight toolkit (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) which has gesturelistener  to get gesture events.  It looks like some external library to add in the application. I’m wording are there any API comes with WP7 sdk right from Microsoft. But didn’t found anything  so far.

I  used MouseEventHandler and MouseButtonEventHandler to get any touch event in the emulator. It is not convient for a complicated multi touch, etc.

Please give me so link to study and discover gesture API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight toolkit is an external library (to the SDK) but it is produced by people working at Microsoft. Most of the developers of the toolkit also work on the SDK. It is a way for them to release more controls but on a more frequent schedule than the main SDK.

The XNA framework contains some gesture detection but this is typically more complicated to include in a Silverlight application than the toolkit.

You could also write the gesture detection yourself using the manipulation or mouse events but I'd advise against this if possible.
I'd also advise against reinventing the wheel when there are already tools available.

Answer (score 0):

There are gestures built into XNA; but either way, be it Silverlight toolkit or XNA library, you would have to add a reference in your solution.

This would be a nice starting place to learn about gestures in XNA: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-5-Input-touch-gestures.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I have to proceed with silverlight toolkit